# MPMoviePlayerController problem at start

Tags: objective-c, ipad, iphone-sdk-3.2

I have a problem with MPMoviePlayerController, because when I start it in fullscreen it exists, but the song is still playing. I added the MPMoviePlayerDidExitFullscreenNotification notification and it says that when the video starts playin it exists the full screen. Here's my code:

```
_multimediaPlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] init];
_multimediaPlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleDefault;
_multimediaPlayer.initialPlaybackTime = 0;

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(videoPlayBackDidFinish:) 
                                                 name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification 
                                               object:nil];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(videoPlayerDidExitFullscreen:) 
                                                 name:MPMoviePlayerDidExitFullscreenNotification
                                               object:nil];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(videoPlayerPlaybackStateChanged:) 
                                                 name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackStateDidChangeNotification
                                               object:nil];

    NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/mag_%d/%@", [FMUtils documentsFolderPathWithFile:nil], _magID, _pageObject.fileName];
    if ([FMUtils fileExistsAtPath:path]) {
        _multimediaPlayer.contentURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
    } else {
        _multimediaPlayer.contentURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", self.dataURL, _pageObject.fileName]];
    }

    CGSize objectViewSize = self.frame.size;
    _multimediaPlayer.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, objectViewSize.width, objectViewSize.height);
    [self addSubview:_multimediaPlayer.view];

    if (_pageObject.blink)  {
        [_multimediaPlayer setFullscreen:YES animated:YES];
    }

    [_multimediaPlayer play];
```

Most of the time it happens when the video is not downloaded and it needs to stream it.

Do you have any idea why is this happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved while I not listen to MPMoviePlayerPlaybackStateDidChangeNotification.